# i want to delete all duplicates in a column without creating another table, there is no primary key,no index and no other constraint in the table

Tags: mysql

```
|===============================|
|column_one   |     column_two  |
|===============================|
|  red        |      james      |
|  green      |      smith      |
|  blue       |      kelvin     |
|  yellow     |      james      |
|  black      |      james      |
|  purple     |      bawa       |
|  white      |      milky      |
=================================
```

after applying query, there should be

```
|===============================|
|column_one   |     column_two  |
|===============================|
|  red        |                 |
|  green      |      smith      |
|  blue       |      kelvin     |
|  yellow     |                 |
|  black      |                 |
|  purple     |      bawa       |
|  white      |      milky      |
=================================
```

Comment: did you try something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should really try something yourself before coming here and asking for help. However, here's something that should do what you're asking for:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_two=''
WHERE column_two IN (
   SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT column_two FROM table_name
      GROUP BY column_two
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   ) alias_table
)
```

It works by making a sub-query that finds all the duplicates of `column_two`, then the 'parent' query sets all of those records to have `''` in `column_two`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like `DISTINCT` will help you :

```
`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE no_duplicats AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table_name;
DELETE FROM table_name;
INSERT INTO table_name SELECT * FROM no_duplicats;
DROP TABLE no_duplicats;`
```